# Split .csv file using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I have a .csv file contains 100k lines, i use mysql to generate that file.
I want to split that file into smaller files contain 3k lines per file.
How do i do that using mysql or java? and which faster?
I found the solution in java but it take O(n^2) using buffer reader and buffer writer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is **at worst** an O(n) problem.  What was this alleged O(n^2) solution?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Isn't read buffer takes O(n) and outer while takes O(n) ?

Comment: If you start reading at the beginning of the file and keep reading straight through to the end, that's O(n) in the size of the file.  Doesn't matter if you have a loop because the loop only goes around _n_ times at most; fewer if you read more than one character at a time.  It would only be O(n^2) if you read one character at a time, starting from the beginning of the file each time.

Comment: @KevinAnderson right, but how i can manage to create small files each have only 3K lines ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java you can split the file Below example split file using java.I would prefer using unix script we are using in our

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String src="C:\\Users\\sahug\\Downloads\\split\\dumps.txt";
        String dest="C:\\Users\\sahug\\Downloads\\split\\";
        String fileName="MyFile";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(str);
        int size = 20;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[size];

        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            int i = fis.read(buffer, 0, size);
            if (i == -1)
                break;

            String filename = fileName + count;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest+filename);
            fos.write(buffer, 0, i);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            ++count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. (int size = 20) does this mean the new files will have 20 lines ?!

Comment: No that is size of the file I am using in buffer array.Here 20 means 20 bytes

Comment: Ok, but how can i make each file contains 3k only ?!

Comment: Use bufferreader to read line by line then when threshold reach write to file